# how to deal with mixed line endings in diff-mode

Tags: diff-mode

Say I have several files with different line endings (i.e. some have LF and others have CR+LF).  If I somehow run diff on them and load the diff into Emacs (e.g. with `C-x v D`, or just dumping the diff to a file and visiting it), I get mixed line endings in the diff buffer.  This is more than just annoying `^M`s at the end of some lines, it breaks `diff-apply-hunk`.  If I delete the CRs, `diff-apply-hunk` works, but at the expense of editing the buffer, which is undesirable when editing patch files.

How do others deal with this?  Is there a way to make the line endings in the diff buffer consistent without changing the buffer contents?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have so far:

```
(defun diff-delete-trailing-CR ()
  "Delete trailing carriage returns (^M) in a `diff-mode' buffer."
  (when (and (derived-mode-p 'diff-mode)
           (buffer-file-name)
           (save-excursion
             (goto-char (point-min))
             (re-search-forward "\r$" nil t))
           (y-or-n-p "Strip trailing carriage returns? "))
    (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward "\r+$" nil t)
          (replace-match "" nil nil)))
      (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))

(add-hook 'diff-mode-hook #'diff-delete-trailing-CR)
```

It at least ignores non-file buffers and buffers that don't have any CRs.